# Unwind the equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $x, y, z, t$ be positive integers. Given that
$$68(xyzt+xy+zt+xt+1)=157(yzt+y+t)$$
Find the value of the product $xyzt$. I couldn't even start with the problem. I just know that the expression n the left bracket is a multiple of $157$ and that in the right bracket is a multiple of $68$. Then what do I do?

Comment: Where does this problem come from, please?

Comment: I better not tell it.

Comment: Then no one had better answer it.

Comment: How does the source matter?

Comment: It matters to me. You keep your secrets, I'll keep mine.

Comment: Okay, you want the source. One of my friends in the United States is taught by Titu Andreescu. He gave it to him and my friend gave it to me. If that makes you happy...

Comment: And is Andreescu happy with problems intended for your friend being posted to the internet?

Comment: I say --- do you have permission from Professor Andreescu to post to the internet problems he gave to your friend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to individ. His approach made me thinking and here is the solution.From the given equation,
$$\frac{157}{68}=\frac{xyzt+xy+zt+xt+1}{yzt+y+z}$$$$=\frac{x(yzt+y+t)+zt+1}{yzt+y+z}$$$$=x+\frac{zt+1}{yzt+y+z}$$$$=x+\frac{1}{\frac{yzt+y+z}{zt+1}}$$$$=x+\frac{1}{\frac{y(zt+1)+z}{zt+1}}$$$$=x+\frac{1}{y+\frac{z}{zt+1}}$$$$=x+\frac{1}{y+\frac{1}{\frac{zt+1}{z}}}$$$$=x+\frac{1}{y+\frac{1}{t+1/z}}$$
Thus, we want to write the fraction $\frac{157}{68}$ as a continued fraction:
$\frac{157}{68}=2+\frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{4+1/5}}$ Therefore, $x=2, y=3, z=4, t=5$. Hence $xyzt=120$.

Comment: Very pretty, nice work!

Answer (score -1):

This equation is written differently.

$$x=\frac{157(yzt+t+y)-68(zt+1)}{68(yzt+y+t)}$$

$$x=\frac{157}{68}-\frac{zt+1}{yzt+y+t}$$

Means  $x=1$   and then.    $$89(yzt+y+t)=68(zt+1)$$    $$y=\frac{68(zt+1)-89t}{89(zt+1)}=\frac{68}{89}-\frac{t}{zt+1}$$    So no positive solutions.

For the case when   $x=2$  I made a mistake.

The procedure is the same.  $$21(yzt+y+t)=68(zt+1)$$

$$y=\frac{68}{21}-\frac{t}{zt+1}$$  $$\frac{a}{21}=\frac{t}{zt+1}$$

$a=5 ; 26 ; 47 $  - And as a consequence it is necessary to iterate.

$$t=\frac{a}{21-az}$$

Never saw that  $21-5z=1$   That means  $z=4$

Comment: Why can't x be equal to 2.